# Extracting version information using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract version information from the following string

```
993-756-V01 ver 02a
```

What regex I need to use in order to extract **01** and **02** from     993-756-V**01** ver **02**a

I tried to extract the version substring i.e. **V01 ver 02a** with the below regex.

```
[A-Z][0-9]{2} ver [0-9]{2}
```

But is there a more direct way to extract the information

Comment: [`V(\d+)\s*ver\s*(\d+)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/pmUjh2/1)

Comment: I suggest adding *groups*: `[A-Z](?<major>[0-9]{2}) ver (?<minor>[0-9]{2})`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: How do I achieve grouping when it doesn't recognise the <major> and <minor> entries beforehand. Do you mean this way `[A-Z]([0-9]{2}) ver ([0-9]{2})`

Comment: @this-Me: What do you mean by *it doesn't recognise the <major> and <minor> entries beforehand*? The regex matches and captures the necessary details into the "major" and "minor" groups. See Dmitry's [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5bA-Z%5d%28%3f%3cmajor%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%29+ver+%28%3f%3cminor%3e%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%29&i=993-756-V01+ver+02a). You may also use `[A-Z](?<major>[0-9]+) ver (?<minor>[0-9]+)`

Comment: Exactly how do I use this major and minor grouping in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex with *named capturing groups* to capture the information you need. See the following code:

```
var s = "993-756-V01 ver 02a";
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<major>[0-9]+)\s+ver\s+(?<minor>[0-9]+)");
if (result.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Major: {0}\nMinor: {1}", 
        result.Groups["major"].Value, result.Groups["minor"].Value);
}
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/B2nwEw)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<major>[0-9]+)` - Group "major" capturing 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `ver\s+` - `ver` substring and then 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<minor>[0-9]+)` -  Group "minor" capturing 1+ digits

Comment: Thanks for simplifying this for me. I had over complicated the groups using Linq this way  <code>`foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
                {
                    List<Group> groupList = new List<Group>(match.Groups.Cast<Group>());
                    Group[] groupResult = groupList.Where((n) => n.Length == 2).ToArray<Group>();
                    if (groupResult.Length > 1)
                    {
                        majorVersion = groupResult[0].Value;
                        minorVersion = groupResult[1].Value;
                    }
                }`</code>

Comment: Yes, that is a lot of redundant code. If my answer proved helpful, please also consider upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another short possibilility i see is to use the below pattern:

```
V(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

Here:

```
V     = Literal `V` capital alphabet.
(\d+) = Captures any digit from 0-9 following `V` character. 
\D+   = Anything except digit next to digits. (A way to find the next numeric part of your version number)
(\d+) = Captures any digit from 0-9 following non-digit characters.
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/BQPvqZhAuJ)